# How to enable CPU platform for OpenCL applications?

Tags: amd-processor, opencl

I am currently running Ubuntu 16.04 on a machine with an AMD A8-5600K APU and a Radeon R9 270X. The amdgpu driver does not yet support my card and therefore I cannot use OpenCL on my GPU. However, I see no reason why OpenCL applications can't use my CPU.

I've installed every package I can think of - [ocl-icd-libopencl1 [image: Install ocl-icd-libopencl1]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ocl-icd-libopencl1), [ocl-icd-opencl-dev [image: Install ocl-icd-opencl-dev]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ocl-icd-opencl-dev), etc.

I've written [a simple application](https://gist.github.com/nathan-osman/963e800c5735334ce0ec) that enumerates available OpenCL platforms and  it fails on the `clGetPlatformIDs()` call. What am I missing?

---

**Edit:** I installed the AMD APP SDK as recommended in SE6's answer but no platforms were showing up yet. Running `strace` revealed that the OpenCL ICD loader couldn't find `libamdocl64.so`.

---

**Further edit:** success! I was able to get it working using the following command:

```
sudo ln -s '/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/lib/x86_64/sdk/libamdocl64.so' \
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libamdocl64.so
```

(Replace `/opt` with the path you installed the AMD APP SDK to.)

Comment: On actual CPU, or iGPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the AMD APP SDK from the [AMD website](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) you should then see your CPU available as an OpenCL device.

Comment: I managed to get it installed but the ICD doesn't seem to work. Still getting "no platforms".

Comment: I updated the question to reflect progress in debugging this.

Comment: ...and finally success!