# OpenCL On ubuntu 16.04, Intel Sandy Bridge CPU

Tags: 16.04, opencl, sandy-bridge

Is it possible to install openCL on 16.04 (CPU-Only)?
I tried many guides, but still do not get a working box.
I have a sandy-bridge second gen CPU, if this matters.

Comment: amd cpu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/821341/how-to-enable-cpu-platform-for-opencl-applications

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### install packets

#### Generic ubuntu packages for OpenCL

Basic installation

`sudo apt install ocl-icd-libopencl1
sudo apt install opencl-headers
sudo apt install clinfo`

#### Package that allows to compile OpenCL code (1.2 I think)

Needed to link and compile

`sudo apt install ocl-icd-opencl-dev`

### For Intel GT core

#### Package that enables runnig openCL on Intel GT, IvyBridge and up

`sudo apt install beignet`

### For SandyBridge Intel CPU and possible others

Download this file
OpenCL™ Runtime 16.1.1 for Intel® Core™ and Intel® Xeon® Processors for Ubuntu* (64-bit)
On https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_linux_SDK_release

Install packages for turning rpm to deb

`sudo apt-get install -y rpm alien libnuma1`

Untar downloaded file

`tar -xvf opencl_runtime_16.1.1_x64_ubuntu_6.4.0.25.tgz
cd opencl_runtime_16.1.1_x64_ubuntu_6.4.0.25/rpm/`

Turn rpm files to deb

`fakeroot alien --to-deb opencl-1.2-base-6.4.0.25-1.x86_64.rpm
fakeroot alien --to-deb opencl-1.2-intel-cpu-6.4.0.25-1.x86_64.rpm`

Install .deb packages

`sudo dpkg -i opencl-1.2-base_6.4.0.25-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i opencl-1.2-intel-cpu_6.4.0.25-2_amd64.deb`

Touch local config file

`sudo touch /etc/ld.so.conf.d/intelOpenCL.conf`

Open the file 

`sudo vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/intelOpenCL.conf`

and add the line

> /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-6.4.0.25/lib64/clinfo

Create a vendors dir and add intel.icd

`sudo mkdir -p /etc/OpenCL/vendors
sudo ln /opt/intel/opencl-1.2-6.4.0.25/etc/intel64.icd /etc/OpenCL/vendors/intel64.icd
sudo ldconfig`

### test if this worked

Command to list your devices

`clinfo`

Dowload this file

> https://codeload.github.com/hpc12/tools/tar.gz/master

Run this code to make sure everything works

`tar xzvf tools-master.tar.gz 
cd tools-master
make
./print-devices
./cl-demo 1000 10`

This should print out GOOD in the end

## For Nvidia

install nvidia drivers (I used 370), this should include all the runtime dirvers

## Usefull linkes I have used to put this together

https://wiki.tiker.net/OpenCLHowTo
http://korniychuk.org.ua/instruction/how-to-use-opencl-on-ubuntu-16-04/
https://laanwj.github.io/2016/05/06/opencl-ubuntu1604.html
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#latest_linux_SDK_release
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl/topic/285869
https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-06-24/install-opencl-on-debianubuntu-orderly/
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl/topic/390630
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977216/opencl-compile-on-linux

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me on Ubuntu 17.04 on Intel NUC with i3 (Kaby Lake)

Answer (score 3):

As per [Intel's support site](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/graphics-drivers/000005524.html), OpenCL is not supported on 2nd gen (Sandy Bridge) Core processors.

You will need a 3rd gen (Ivy Bridge) or newer CPU to use OpenCL 1.2, or a 7th gen (Kaby Lake) to have the option to use OpenCL 2.0 with the Intel GPU (I am not sure what is currently supported in the drivers available for Linux).

Comment: I found this forum thread where some one says he was able to make the CPU only work with openCL 1.2.
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl/topic/285869
That would be enough for me.
But I am also not sure if 16.04 is supported.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL is packaged in Ubuntu/Debian, so rather than manually installing, one could try installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install beignet-opencl-icd ocl-icd-libopencl1 clinfo
```

(or `intel-opencl-icd` instead of `beignet-opencl-icd` for Ubuntu 22.04+)

Then run `clinfo` to make sure that it detects your OpenCL platforms and devices.

```
$ clinfo

Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Intel Gen OCL Driver
  Platform Vendor                                 Intel
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 2.0 beignet 1.3
```