# How can i enable opencl devices (GPU) on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: intel-graphics, amd-graphics, gpu, opencl, amdgpu

When i type this in the command line

```
clinfo
```

i see this

```
Number of platforms 0
```

How can i enable opencl platforms on on my computer/GPU?
i am using ubuntu 16.04 and my computer is lenovo G50-80
i searched for the GPU model of my computer and found
[my GPU model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoVdW.png).
i know it's a simple question but i don't know a lot about hardware.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/850281/opencl-on-ubuntu-16-04-intel-sandy-bridge-cpu/850594#850594